# javascript string.replace against negative list

Tags: javascript, regex

I know it's preferable to use a whitelist when dealing with regexp, but due to client requirement I can't do that. They don't want us to prevent the user from entering special characters - we need to allow them to enter them, and then strip them out before saving.

So say I have something like this:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    var test = $('#pizza').val();
    var pattern = /[a-z][0-9]/;
    if (!pattern.test(test)) {
        console.log("not pass: " + test);
    }
    else {
        console.log("passes");
    }
})
```

How can I do a `string.replace()` and replace any characters in `test` that *aren't* in the pattern?

ETA: here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mu9D5/2/); if you enter something like `Esther (test*&^) pizza` in the input field, I want it to return `Esther test pizza`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your regex like this:

```
var test = $('#pizza').val();
var pattern = /[^\w\s]+/g;
if (pattern.test(test)) {
    console.log("not pass: " + test);
    var cleanVal = test.replace(pattern, '');   
    // set cleanVal to wherever you want
    $('#pizza').val(cleanVal);
}
else {
    console.log("passes");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct pattern is `/[a-z0-9]/`, not `/[a-z][0-9]/`.

The best solution would involve changing a little the expression :

```
var cleanString = test.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g,'');
```

If you can't, then you can do this :

```
var cleanString = test.match(/[a-z0-9]/g).join('');
```

Comment: I tried `/[a-z0-9]/`, and it allowed `123@` and `1@23` to pass.

Comment: You mean if you use the test function ? In that function you must make the regex cover the whole string : /^[a-z0-9]*$/

Comment: This will fail on capital letters.

Comment: @JustinMorgan That's the pattern of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to remove the unwanted characters

```
var test = test.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, ""); //g means all, i means case insensitve
```